# Need jQuery to fire on all dropdowns and not fire multiple times

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get a jQuery function to fire no matter which drop down is changed.  There are several dropdowns on the page.  I tried

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $('select').each(function () {
            CalcOral();
       });
 });
```

A couple of problems I haven't figured out yet:

1. on the load, the CalcOral is fired off for each dropdown.  I only need it to fire once.
2. when I change a drop down the CalcOral does not fire.  There are no errors but it does not run.

Thanks
Shannon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try jQuery .change()

```
$('select').change(function(){ CalcOral();});
```

Comment: This doesn't address the first concern.

Comment: it did.. it fixed both issue.

Comment: I'm not sure how. It doesn't run your function on load.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. on the load, the CalcOral is fired off for each dropdown. I only need it to fire once.

so just call it once in ready function

> when I change a drop down the CalcOral does not fire. There are no
>   errors but it does not run.

bind onchange event in ready function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        CalcOral(); // prob1 solved

      $('select').change(function () {
            CalcOral(); // prob 2 solved
       });   
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the function on load, and again on change:

```
function CalcOral() {
    // do stuff;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('select').change(function () {
        CalcOral();
    });

    CalcOral();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a0sneL6u/)**

Answer (score 0):

You're making it too complicated, here's a very short line doing what you need :

```
$('select').change(CalcOral);
```

Which is a shortcut for the more generic jQuery binding funtion 'on' :

```
$('select').on("change",CalcOral);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is firing for each drop down on load because of your .each loop.  It is not firing on change because you did not bind it (and presumably you didn't add an onchange function to the selects either).

I'd recommend two things:
1.  Just run CalcOral() directly from your onload.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      CalcOral();

});
```

2. Either add onchange function calls to the html or an a jquery bind event.  For this case a .change would work but jQuery generally recommends the slightly more versatile .on function.  Both can work, up to you.

   ```
   $('select').change(function(){
       CalcOral();
   )};
   ```

The bind event will run every time any of the select's is changed.